# Find point $B$ on a line such that $|A_1B|^2 + |A_2B|^2 + \cdots + |A_nB|^2$ has minimal value.

Tags: geometry, inequality, optimization

There are $N$ points $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ on the same side of line $p$. Find point $B$ laying on the line $p$ such that $|A_1B|^2 + |A_2B|^2 + \cdots + |A_nB|^2$ has lowest possible value.

Comment: Is it really important that the points are on the same side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left |A_k B\right|^2 $$
is just the rotational [inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia) of the set $E=\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ with respect to $B$.

If $B$ have to lie on some line $p$, the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) gives that the inertia is minimized by the projection on $p$ of the centroid of $E$, given by $\frac{A_1+\cdots+A_n}{n}$. You may check that also by considering a coordinate system in which the line $p$ is the $x$-axis, and by minimizing (with respect to $x$) the quadratic form representing the inertia in such coordinate system.

Comment: Could you describe it using easier mathematical language? :)

Comment: @user4201961: yes. Do your math, and it will become obvious.